# Problem with Snort rule

Tags: snort

```
alert tcp $HOME_NET any -> $EXTERNAL_NET 80 (msg:"Get2 method"; flow: to_server, established; dsize: >20; sid:1000006; priority: 15)
```

Snort does not generate any alert, whereas when I write the following rule:

```
alert tcp $HOME_NET any -> $EXTERNAL_NET 80 (msg:"Get1 method"; flow: to_server, established; dsize: <20; sid:1000005; priority: 15)
```

it does generate alert

Answer (score 1):

As Snort manual is claiming:

> The dsize keyword is used to test the packet payload size. This may be used to check for abnormally sized packets that might cause buffer overflows.
>
> This example looks for a dsize that is between 300 and 400 bytes.
>
> `dsize:300<>400;`

So, this setup is causing the generation and the not-generation of the alert.

Comment: I think the OP is running only one version the alert, not both at once.

Comment: @Schroeder I believe the point made by nick is that the dsize condition is not being satisfied when it is configured to be "dsize: >20". The implication is that the testing done by the OP does not provoke any packet with payload size greater than 20 bytes.